# Hazelcast Pub-Sub, subscriber not receiving messages

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am following this very simple example found here: https://github.com/ardlema/hazelcast-pubsub/tree/master/src/main/java/org/ardlema/hazelcast

I modified it a little to use strings:

--publisher

```
package org.ardlema.hazelcast;

import com.hazelcast.core.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class Publisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        ITopic<String> topic = hz.getTopic("topic");
        topic.publish("Hello World");
    }
}
```

-- Subscriber

```
package org.ardlema.hazelcast;

import java.util.Date;

import com.hazelcast.core.*;

public class Subscriber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        ITopic<String> topic = hz.getTopic("topic");
        topic.addMessageListener(new MessageListenerImpl());
        System.out.println("Subscribed");
    }

    private static class MessageListenerImpl implements MessageListener<String> {
        public void onMessage(Message<String> m) {
            System.out.println("Received: " + m.getMessageObject());
        }
    }
}
```

I run these as two separate apps, first I run the subscriber then I run the publisher. The problem is the subscriber never gets the message that is published. Why is this the case?

UPDATE: I tested this exact same code on a different computer and it worked...but I still need to get it to work on the original computer but i am still not sure why it is not working

Comment: If it worked on a different machine, then it's probably up to your environment. What is the difference between the environment where it worked and the "original" environment?

Comment: The main difference is the one that worked was tested on Windows and the other on Linux. It works on Linux environment when I put both the pub/sub in the same java application but not when it is two separate apps (which is what I need). I agree it is most likely something in the environment but which parts specifically could potentially cause it to not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your 2 (embedded) Hazelcast instances do not form one cluster. Please check the discovery part. By default, Hazelcast uses Multicast for discovery. You should see something like this in logs.

```
Members {size:2, ver:2} [
  Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - e40081de-056a-4ae5-8ffe-632caf8a6cf1 this
  Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 - 93e82109-16bf-4b16-9c87-f4a6d0873080
]
```

Read more at [Hazelcast Documentation: Discovery Mechanisms](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/clusters/discovery-mechanisms.html)